# Today's date -30 days in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get today's date -30 days but in the format of: "2016-06-08"

I have tried `setDate(date.getDate() - 30);` for -30 days.

I have tried `date.toISOString().split('T')[0]` for the format.

Both work, but somehow cannot be used together.

Comment: Could you demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Preferably, you'd subtract the number of milliseconds 30 days is, from the current timestamp.

Comment: Would have been better if you had provided the full code so people can see where/why it is not working. See [mcve]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) doesn't return a `Date` object, it returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. You need separate calls:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
var dateString = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]; // "2016-06-08"
```

Comment: How does this method compare to if you subtracted 30-day's worth of milliseconds from a timestamp?

Comment: @vtange Not sure I understand what you mean. OP had code like this (I assume): `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30).toISOString().split('T')[0]`, which won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that you would be better to use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this rather than reinventing the wheel. However a straight JS solution without libraries is something like:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
```

sets `date` to 30 days ago. (JS automatically accounts for leap years and rolling over months less than 30 days, and into the previous year)

now just output it like you want (gives you more control over the output). Note we are prepending a '0' so that numbers less than 10 are 0 prefixed

```
var dateString = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
```

Comment: moment.js is indeed the way to go.

Comment: why use a library for something that can be done reliably using native methods in just a few lines?

Comment: @charlietfl Unless things have changed, even modern browsers have small differences in date handling.

Comment: Adding an entire library of 20 000 bytes *(minimized and zipped)* to do something that can be done with 20 bytes, seems like madness to me ?

Comment: @charlietfl, agreed. However, i mention it so that if OP is likely to need other styles of date handling/formatting/conversion in future, it is in the back of their mind :)

Comment: @Stijn woudn't be any difference cross browser with anything anyone is using in any of these answers

Answer (score 4):

You're saying that those two lines worked for you and your problem is combining them. Here is how you do that:

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you really want to subtract exactly 30 days, then this code is fine, but if you want to subtract a month, then obviously this code doesn't work and it's better to use a library like moment.js as other have suggested than trying to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Format date object into a YYYY-MM-DD string
const formatDate = (date) => (date.toISOString().split('T')[0]);

const currentDate = new Date();

// Values in milliseconds
const currentDateInMs = currentDate.valueOf();
const ThirtyDaysInMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

const calculatedDate = new Date(currentDateInMs - ThirtyDaysInMs);

console.log(formatDate(currentDate));
console.log(formatDate(calculatedDate));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Today's date -30 days in this format: "YYYY-MM-DD":

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
var dateString = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]; // "2021-02-05"
```

Today's date -30 days but get all days in this format: "YYYY-MM-DD":

```
var daysDate = [];
for(var i = 1; i<= 30; i++) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - i);
    daysDate.push(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]); // ["2021-02-05", "2021-02-04", ...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can calculate in terms of timestamp

```js
var date = new Date(); // Current date
console.log(date.toDateString())
var pre_date = new Date(date.getTime() - 30*24*60*60*1000); 
// You will get the Date object 30 days earlier to current date.
console.log(pre_date.toDateString())
```

Here `30*24*60*60*1000` refers to time difference in miliseconds.