# Setting date to one month prior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Reactjs `DatePicker` and I am trying to set my `startDate` function one month prior to today's date.

I have the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

class DateInput extends Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date()
  };

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date });
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <FormText>From</FormText>
        <span>
          <DatePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.startDate} />
        </span>
        <span>
          <DatePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.endDate} />
        </span>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default DateInput;
```

Comment: I assume the DatePicker uses a standard JS date, so using something like this should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937257/1650337

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Today's date -30 days in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276672/todays-date-30-days-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to do date subtraction like so

```
 let startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(d.getDate()-30);
let endDate = new Date();

state = {
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate
  };
```

Hope this helps.